# In SSRS, how do I conditionally format the background color of the lines of a table AFTER the visibility expression has resolved?

Tags: reporting-services, format

My company has reporting standards that require the lines of a table to alternate in color for readability purposes. I know how to do that, however the latest report that I am working on has conditional visibility on each line.

What happens is that the alternating background color gets applied to the table before the visibility condition gets checked, leaving a the report with no pattern of background color to speak of.

I have searched for any kind of setting to change when certain property expressions get applied to a table. There doesn't seem to be one.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8365ca9b-7a50-4024-a706-4516ed12c038/how-to-maintain-alternating-row-background-colors-while-making-blank-rows-invisible?forum=sqlreportingservices

Instead of applying the formatting across all rows, I only apply it using the same visibility conditions that hides the rows in question. The example in the link uses blank rows where I will use some extra logic instead.

Answer (score 0):

This article deals with the RowNumber function in SSRS.  It contains an example of alternating row colors in the Tablix.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-rownumber-function?view=sql-server-ver15

```
=IIF(RowNumber("GroupbyCategory") Mod 2, "White", "PaleGreen")
```

Comment: Thank you B. - I have that part down, the problem is that the alternating row colors are being applied before the visibility condition removes some rows. This leaves my table with rows that no longer alternate.